# Дилемма с предложеньицем

Tags: недопустимая-метка

У Аверченко есть такое предложение (вернее, часть его): "делая размах аршина четыре", у меня оно превратилось в "делая размах в четыре аршина". У кого правильней? Если же оба варианта верны, то разъясните, пожалуйста, аверченковский.

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее будет так: ***делая размах  аршина в два.***

1) Перестановка связана с указанием приблизительного размера.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Но эти огромные окна едва могут освещать комнату, ибо стены её **аршина в три толщиною.**.. [В. А. Жуковский. Очерки Швеции (1838)]

Полилась вода, смешанная с кровью, розовая селезёнка **аршина в два величиною**...Акула сразу сделалась легче, и её без труда вытащили на палубу.  [Н. С. Гумилев. Африканский дневник (1913)] [

В руках держал деревянный шест **аршина в три длиною.** [В. Лихоносов. Ненаписанные воспоминания. Наш маленький Париж. Ч. 1-2 (1983)]

2) **Беспредложное  управление** тоже применяется, но при более понятном синтаксисе:

А помещение арестное было низкое, **аршина два с небольшим...**

У склона холмов вытекал из трещины в камне большой ключ, заполняя впадину **аршина два в диаметре**...

Кенигсека не сразу нашли, хотя в ручье всего было **аршина два глубины.**

Между замечательнейшими редкостями, находившимися в квартире Павла Воиновича, был один двухэтажный стеклянный домик **аршина два длины...**

Он ... увидел тюк, упакованный в рогожу, **длиной аршина два.**

3) **В современном варианте** это может выглядеть так: Прошли километра два.   Дерево метра в два высотою/метра два высотою.

Comment: При "делая размах" гораздо лучше звучит предлог "на": *делая размах на аршина четыре*.

Comment: Тогда лучше "аршина на четыре".

Comment: @Alex_ander Ваш порядок лучше, если об аршинах говорилось ранее: *На сколько аршинов у него размах? — Ну, аршина на четыре.*

Comment: Проголосовал за ваш ответ. Странно, что никто не проголосовал, в целом он правильный. Мне не понятно, почему вы отдаёте предпочтение варианту с предлогом? Ведь смысл не меняется: «размах аршина два» и «размах аршина в два». Что даёт предлог?

Comment: Спасибо за голос. (Кажется, это первые шаги нового профиля – про голосование.)  Предлог обозначает грамматическую связь управление (иначе связь не будет обозначена), поэтому это основной вариант. Беспредложное управление нужно считать разговорным вариантом, с точки зрения правильной грамматики.  Я ориентировалась на сведения из Краткой русской грамматики  (управление).

Comment: _«Кажется, это первые шаги нового профиля — про голосование»_ я не знаю о чём вы. Какой новый профиль?

Comment: Я тоже прочитал в Русской грамматике, что без предлога разговорный вариант, однако в задачах по математике и физике никогда не пишут предлог «в»: _«Прямоугольник имеет длину 6 см и ширину 4 см…»_, _«Первую половину пути автомобиль двигается со скоростью 60 км/ч, а вторую — со скоростью 40 км/ч»_. Разве можно назвать тексты задач в учебниках разговорным стилем? Почему так?

Comment: Могу предположить, что это особенности специальной темы. В математике  такая формулировка встречается часто, поэтому она понятна и без предлога. Можно считать, что в данном случае выбор варианта зависит от стиля и от структуры самого выражения. Иногда отсутствие предлога кажется просторечным, в других же случаях вполне допустимым.  А профиль - это я про себя вспомнила, за новые имена  без репутации неохотно голосуют, даже если они говорят что-то правильное.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.